# Access to excel through VBA, number display error

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a small VBA code to export data from access to excel, when it is exported all the number formats are displayed as date in excel. I checked format in Access database its right. Could you please tell me how to display them as numbers. All the columns which are number are displayed as Date so it would be great if that code line checks for all the columns and display the correct/default format.

For reference my code,

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()


 'Defining database variable
  Dim dbnxair As DAO.Database
  'Defining Excel variable
   Dim excelnxair As Excel.Application
  'Defining workbook variable
  Dim wrkbooknxair As Excel.Workbook
 'Defining Worksheets
 Dim wrksheetnxair As Excel.Worksheet
'Defining recordset
 Dim recsetnxair As Recordset
'Defining Querydef
 Dim querynxair As QueryDef
 'Defining query as string
 Dim strSQL As String
 'Defining condition string
Dim strlistcondition As String


'Opening the database
 Set dbnxair = CurrentDb()

'Creating the Excel object
Set excelnxair = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 'Opening the worksheet
  excelnxair.Visible = True

  'Creating a new workbook
 Set wrkbooknxair = excelnxair.Workbooks.Add
 wrkbooknxair.SaveAs "C:\Users\z003cnxt\Desktop\new1.xls"

  'Creating a new worksheet
 Set wrksheetnxair = excelnxair.Sheets(1)

 'Creating a query
Set querynxair = dbnxair.CreateQueryDef("")

 For Each varItem In Me!List2.ItemsSelected
   strlistcondition = strlistcondition & ",'" & Me!List2.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem

strlistcondition = Right(strlistcondition, Len(strlistcondition) - 1)

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Std Table] WHERE ([Std Table].Country IN(" & strlistcondition    & "));"

'Adding Sql statement
 querynxair.SQL = strSQL



'Creating and opening the recordset
 Set recsetnxair = querynxair.OpenRecordset()

  'Copying data to excel sheet
  excelnxair.Cells.CopyFromRecordset recsetnxair


  'Adding field names in each columns
 For lvlcolumn = 0 To recsetnxair.Fields.Count - 1
   excelnxair.Cells(1, lvlcolumn + 1).Value = recsetnxair.Fields(lvlcolumn).Name
 Next

 wrksheetnxair.Cells.AutoFilter
wrksheetnxair.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit


  Set dbnxair = Nothing
 Set recsetnxair = Nothing
  Set querynxair = Nothing
 Set wrkbooknxair = Nothing
Set wrksheetnxair = Nothing
Set excelnxair = Nothing

For Each varItem In Me!List2.ItemsSelected
  Me!List2.Selected(varItem) = False
Next varItem


End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`? For parameter `TableName`, you would be able to use your `SELECT` query.

Comment: Could you please give me the exact syntax for transferspreadsheet bcoz it gives me error when i use with the recordset

Comment: TransferSpreadsheet does not work on recordsets. You can use instead of implementing your own code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by setting all the numberformat as sFormat in my code that worked. But still I am yet to find the solution for dateformat.

Regards,
jeeva